# Pause video on native Chrome HTML5 Player with TamperMonkey Script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to set a `TamperMonkey` script to make a keyboard key pause the native Chrome video player without the need to click on it or use the `Space Bar`

To achieve this, I tried to set a script that would trigger the click action in an `x, y coordinate` where the video is displayed on the page.

So far, it didn't work.

```
// PAUSE VIDEO - ASSIGNED TO *Q* KEY
    (function(){
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 81 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
    document.elementFromPoint(448, 540).click(); // this should trigger the click on video to pause event
    }
    }, false);
    })();
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how to make this video pause with the key `Q`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native [`HTMLVideoElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement)'s don't play/pause when clicked on (at least in Google Chrome; in Safari on MacOS they do, but you shouldn't rely on specific browers), so you'll need to use the `.play()` and `.pause()` methods, determining whether to play or pause based off of that `.paused` readonly boolean. It would be great if there was just a `.togglePlayback()` method, but there isn't.

(BTW, [using `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is depricated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#deprecated) in favor of [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). It still works in major web browsers for backwards compatibility, but it's been officially deprecated in the standards)

On StackOverflow, make sure that you click anywhere inside the code snippet (the white box) once you click the blue button.

```js
(function () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.key == 'q' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
                const video = document.querySelector('video');
                // or = document.elementFromPoint(448, 540); if that's where it will always be
                if (video.paused) video.play();
                else video.pause();
            }
        },
    );
})();
```

```html
<!-- Simple video example -->
<!-- 'Big Buck Bunny' licensed under CC 3.0 by the Blender foundation. Hosted by archive.org -->
<!-- Poster from peach.blender.org -->
<video controls
    src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
    poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/title_anouncement.jpg?x11217"
    width="300">
</video>
```